# Magento : REST API integration with paypal payment method

Tags: magento2, rest-api, paypal-express

We are using REST API for mobile app from magento 2. We are try to place order using paypal express checkout method. But we get error. Check detail bellow.

**API call.**

**Call Type** : PUT

**API URL** : https://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/carts/302/order

**Request Body**

```
{
    "paymentMethod": {
          "method": "paypal_express",
          "additional_data": {
                 "paypal_express_payment_payload": {
                       "create_time":"2019-04-15T23:13:52Z",
                       "id":"PAY-6RV70583SB702805EKEYSZ6Y",
                       "intent":"sale",
                       "state":"approved"
                 }
          }
    }
}
```

**Response of API call :**

{
    "message": "Internal Error. Details are available in Magento log file. Report ID: webapi-5cb8df18c6197"
}

**Magento Error log**

```
    [2019-04-18 20:33:28] main.CRITICAL: Report ID: webapi-5cb8df18c6197; Message: Notice: Array to string conversion in /vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/TypeProcessor.php on line 473 
{"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Report ID: webapi-5cb8df18c6197; Message: Notice: Array to string conversion in /vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/TypeProcessor.php on line 473 
at /vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:206, Exception(code: 0): Notice: Array to string conversion in /vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/TypeProcessor.php on line 473 at /vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"} []
```

Here is my postman screenshot.

[image]

[image]

**Response after developer mode enabled**

[image]

Comment: can you post your whole code on making put request or a screenshot in postman

Comment: @magefms i have added postman code. please check it.

Comment: I see. how about the headers?

Comment: @magefms now i added headers.

Comment: everything is good. The error is weird can you please enable developer mode and check if the exact error will come out

Answer (score 0):

As far I understood, It is a known issue of `Magento 2`. You need to wrote a module with a preference for `Magento\Quote\Observer\Frontend\Quote\Address\VatValidator` in your module `di.xml` and copied the `validate` method

Added these lines of code in the method

```
if (is_array($quoteAddress->getRegion()))
{
                $regionData = $quoteAddress->getRegion();
                if (array_key_exists('region_code', $regionData))
                {
                    $quoteAddress->setRegionCode($regionData['region_code']);
                }
                if (array_key_exists('region_id', $regionData))
                {
                    $quoteAddress->setRegionId($regionData['region_id']);
                }
                $quoteAddress->setRegion(null);
}
```

before Store validation

```
// Store validation results in corresponding quote address
  $quoteAddress->setVatIsValid((int)$validationResult->getIsValid());
  $quoteAddress->setVatRequestId($validationResult->getRequestIdentifier());
```

Reference: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12612

**I hope this will help**

Comment: @JalpeshPatel Have you resolve your query?